# Magento 2 - How to get cron time in controller

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

in Magento 2, I want to get value of "**Generate Schedules Every**" text box location under

> Admin->STORES->ADVANCED->System->Cron (Scheduled Tasks)->Cron
>   configuration options for group: default

Want this value in controller. Can anyone tell me how can we get this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function getConfig($config_path)
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}

public function execute() {

$schedule_generate_every = $this->getConfig('system/cron/default/schedule_generate_every');
$schedule_ahead_for = $this->getConfig('system/cron/default/schedule_ahead_for');
$schedule_lifetime = $this->getConfig('system/cron/default/schedule_lifetime');
$history_cleanup_every = $this->getConfig('system/cron/default/history_cleanup_every');
$history_success_lifetime = $this->getConfig('system/cron/default/history_success_lifetime');
$history_failure_lifetime = $this->getConfig('system/cron/default/history_failure_lifetime');
$use_separate_process = $this->getConfig('system/cron/default/use_separate_process');

}
```

Comment: Happy coding :)